# supabase: how to reference files within tables

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I want my users to be able to upload reports (PDFs). For this purpose, I have created a table of "reports" and thought that I can reference the object stored there. Therefore I created a column "file" with the foreign key reference to the object store.

This has worked so far, however, I do not get a query to work. Example:

```
const { data } = await supabase
      .from<definitions["reports"]>("reports")
      .throwOnError()
      .select(`id,title,file(id)`);
```

The above example gives me this error:

```
{
   "code":"PGRST200",
   "details":null,
   "hint":"Verify that 'reports' and 'file' exist in the schema 'public' and that there is a foreign key relationship between them. If a new relationship was created, try reloading the schema cache.",
   "message":"Could not find a relationship between 'reports' and 'file' in the schema cache"
}
```

I'm only recently working with Postgres and so I would imagine that a reference across the tables and the files may simply not be possible. Anyway, I would like to know how else I could implement this use case.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't have a relation between two tables.

The solution can be like this:

Create a table - report

```
id,title,file_id,created_by + maybe extra data.
```

You need to generate file_id as a unique key (e.g. use package uuid).

```
final file_id = uuid.v4();
```

Upload a new report to the Storage, but use our generated file_id as filename.

```
{bucket_id}/{user_id}/{file_id}.pdf
```

After that you will have all data in one table (report) and if it's needed to download a file from Storage.